# ajax simple code not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I know I might just be missing a simple thing that's right under my nose, or may not understand ajax at all... but I have a problem - this simple peace of code isn't working, but it's from w3schools and it's the simplest example of ajax working.
Can someone help me, please?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the "ajax_info.txt" file:

> text changed.

Comment: Is `"ajax_info.txt"` a local file? Which browser are you trying `js` at?

Comment: "ajax_info.txt" is a file located in the same folder as the "index.html" and it just contains this:
"text changed"

I'm trying in Chrome

Comment: Are you trying `js` at Question at `file:` protocol? That is, is address at page where you are requesting file `file:///path/to/folder/index.html`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're opening the file in the browser with *file://* or *C:/* protocol you'll get a **cross origin request error** when trying to load '*ajax_info.txt*', the reason for this is to protect your machines private files from being read by browser scripts. To fix this you'll need to use the protocol *http://* which you can do if you install a webserver onto your local machine such as WAMP or MAMP.

Additionally a file called *ajax_info.txt* needs to exist in the same directory as this html file. Otherwise this javascript AJAX call will return an error: **/ajax_info.txt 404 (Not Found)**